# how can i show a notification when an admin asiggne an order to a deliverer LARAVEL?

Tags: laravel, notifications, laravel-7

when i store new order i want th deliverer with "deliverer_id" get notified

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $order = Order::create([

    'deliverer_id' => $request->input('deliverer_id'),
    'product_id' => $request->input('product_id'),
    'responsible_id'=>$request->input('responsible_id'),
    'quantity'=> $request->input('quantity'),
    'totalprice' => $request->input('totalprice'),
    'client_name' => $request->input('client_name'),
    'client_phone' => $request->input('client_phone'),
    'client_city'=> $request->input('client_city'),

    ]);

    return redirect()->route('orders.index');
}
```

i want to show a notification say there is a new order on this view

```
<li class="nav-item btn-rotate dropdown new-order">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="nc-icon nc-bell-55"></i>
                            <p>
                                <span class="badge badge-link text-danger    notif-count" data-count="8">8</span>
                            </p>
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right newor">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New order</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
```

Comment: For realtime notifications check out [Broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/broadcasting). It's event driven and working with `Pusher Channels` or `Redis` (which I would use). Using `Redis` requires the usage of `socket.io`. The communication between server and client can be established using `laravel-echo-server`. This just a short overview about what you have to do for realtime notifications. Detailed instructions are well explained in the docs.

Answer (score -1):

Simple wayout here is to set the flash session data in controller method, for example:

```
session()->flash('newOrderReceived', true);
```

Then on view file, you can check to see if the session has that key. If yes, then show the notification. For example, to show bootstrap4 alert message if session has given key:

```
@if(session('newOrderReceived'))
    <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
        There is a new order
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: For more information regarding the session flash data, check out its documentation at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#flash-data

Comment: As per the documentation, you can also try the following in controller method:

`$request->session()->flash('newOrderReceived', true);`

Comment: Basically, flash the session variable and then check to see if session has that variable in view. If yes, show the notification

Comment: He can use laravel notifications or pusher for such kind of activity